# How to convert Json to URL

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.example.tv/customers/4/profiles");
        Console.WriteLine (Jsondata + "This is Json");
        var postData = "first_name=hello";
        postData += "&last_name=world";
        postData += "&pin=1234";
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        Console.WriteLine (data + "Some Crap Data");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }


        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

I have Json data but i want to convert to it urlencoded right now i am doing it the above way

```
Person p = new Person();
p.Name = "Apple";
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
```

but now i want to convert it to url encoded is there any proper way to do it?

Comment: Can you not `post` instead of `get`?

Comment: the method is request.Method = "POST";

Comment: So you want to URL encode a string? What does JSON have to do with this?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what needs to happen.  If you want to pass URL variables, use `get`.  If you want to pass form variables, use `post` as you have done here.  Json doesnt get url encoded as a post variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.Name = "Apple";

var urlEncodedString = String.Join("&", p.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Select(property => property.Name + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(property.GetValue(p, null).ToString()))
        .ToArray());
```